# Wordpress custom post category

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I am quit new to wordpress and have a problem I cannot seems to solve even with a day of google searching. This is what I did:

1. I have created a custom post type called lookbook. This works fine and I can add new items and such.
2. I added a taxonomy so I could add an category to it.

   ```
   function lookbook_taxonomy() {
   register_taxonomy( 'jeans','lookbook',
       array(
           'hierarchical' => true,
           'label' => 'jeans',
           'query_var' => true,
           'rewrite' => true
       )
   );
   ```

   }
3. Using `wp_query` or `query_posts` I can retrieve the lookbook items and display their content.
4. (problem) When I pres the category link provided by word press the page just goes back to index. The link changes to the desired filter however NO post are being filtered. I tried all kinds of stuff but I can seems to find a way to just press the category link and just diplay those post.

update: (code I used to register post type)

```
add_action('init', 'lookbook_register_post_type');
```

function lookbook_register_post_type() {

```
register_post_type('lookbook', array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('lookbook'),
        'singular_name' => __('lookbook')),
      'public' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'excerpt'
      ),
      'has_archive' => true,
      'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag')
      )
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `'has_archive' => true` to your `register_post_type` arguments array if it's not already there.

Additionally, make sure you have the necessary template files ready. Read up on [Wordpress' Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display).

If you show us the code you used to register the post type, as well as what code makes up "the category link", we might be of more help!

Comment: I already set has_archive to true. I am not sure what I should add to my wordpress theme to make it happen.

Comment: It's still unclear what's happening with your "category link." Are you using `get_category_link` in your template file? And what are you wanting to happen? Is it that you need a taxonomy term archive page with all posts marked "jeans"?

Comment: For instance when I use the_category in the loop it will provide you with a link that onces lick will filter posts. So I want there to be link for every post depends on their caterogy that once clicked show all other posts in that category. Now it will just change the link yet all posts will remain visible (no filtering). I tried making a archive-lookbook.php page but I dont really see that being triggered by anying and I kinda dont really know what to put inside of it